# sonarqube analysis takes too much time from jenkins

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm using sonar for the quality code of a spring boot project, and using Jenkins as a CI server.

the command

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

it takes too much time after releasing (incrementing the version in pom.xml). the first build takes 25 min if I replay the build it takes 3 mins.

I tried to downgrade sonarqube Jenkins plugin didn't work for me.

Comment: You probably need a more powerful processor

Comment: This is quite reasonable time.

Comment: This is also related to the amount of code that is analyzed. You did not provide al lot of information. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.